# How html title is generated in entry index page in CP

Tags: craft3, entry, hook, element

I am trying to find out how HTML title is generated in entry index page in Control Panel.

i know it is generated in `src/templates/_elements/element.html` file   by `$this->hook('cp.elements.element', [$this, '_getCpElementHtml']);` in `src/web/View.php` and i see there is a line in entry.php which calls author with

```
return $author ? Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('_elements/element', ['element' => $author]) : '';
```

but i can't find how craft calls for title attribute.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that first column of table view is special and is called [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/25543763fb8fd7604c352a8273be7e53779632ea/src/templates/_elements/tableview/elements.html#L21)
which calls mentioned hook in question.